# Rafters in loft

Tags: structural-engineering, raft-foundations

I have two which I believe to be tie rafters in my loft. They are 1.2 meters from the boarded floor. They both are wobbly. My question is can I remove them and replace them with vertical timbers to open the space up in the loft

Comment: Just because they are wobbly does not mean there is no load. Pay a structural engineer so you don’t make an even more expensive mistake.

Comment: This should be on https://diy.stackexchange.com.

Comment: the question is extremely vague ... it is not suited at any SE site as it stands